# File component noop=true files moved

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following file endpoint configuration.

```
<endpoint id="cmpFilesEp" uri="file:${sod.input.file.cmp.from}&amp;readLock=none&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;filter=#dateFileFilter&amp;noop=true"/>
```

I do not understand why at the end of processing files are moved to `.camel` directory as I put `noop=true`. Is there any legitimate case when files are moved to `.camel` and `noop=true` is set or this is something wrong with my camel config and I should look into that direction? Camel 2.13 used.

Placeholder is taken from config file and looks like

```
sod.input.file.cmp.from  = ${sfs}\\extracts\\eod?include=.*EF_CMP2_OPEN.*|.*EF_CMP6_OPEN.*
```

Added workaround which works, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work with `noop=true`

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    ((FileEndpoint) getContext().getEndpoint("ref:cmpFilesEp")).setProcessStrategy(new GenericFileNoOpProcessStrategy<File>());
```

Comment: _Not familiar with apache-camel,._ **(1)** I see no `?` after the URL part for the start of the query string = parameters. **(2)** The part of an (HTML) URL after `#` is its anchor. `%23dateFilter`?

Comment: updated regarding 1, changing `#dateFilter` to `%23dateFilter` didn't have any effect